# Fullcalendar's eventSources option value from PHP Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using Fullcalendar V4. I am getting a problem with the eventSources option with PHP Ajax.

In Javascript I am using :

```
var eventSource = "data.php?value1=" + item_id;
calendar.addEventSource(eventSource);
```

From PHP I am sending :

```
echo '[{"id":"1","title":"All Day Event1","start":"2019-08-02","backgroundColor":"red"},{"id":"2","title":"All Day Eventssss2","start":"2019-08-04"},{"id":"3","title":"All Day Eventssss3","start":"2019-08-06"},{"id":"4","title":"All Day Eventssss4","start":"2019-08-08"}]';
```

This is working properly.

Now I want to use the option of eventSources, which is described here:  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object

For this, I am sending from PHP :

```
echo '[{"events" : [{"title" : "event1", "start" : "2019-08-01"},{"title" : "event2", "start" : "2019-08-05"}],"color" : "black"}]';
```

But this is not working. No error is showing in the console.

Please help!

Comment: try `echo '{"events" : [{"title" : "event1", "start" : "2019-08-01"},{"title" : "event2", "start" : "2019-08-05"}],"color" : "black"}';`

Comment: You have misunderstood, that's not how event sources works. With event sources there is no need to change anything in your server output. Instead it merely allows you to define more than one URL as being the source of your events, so it can combine data from multiple places in the client-side calendar. The existing URL and the existing server code does not change.

Comment: The event source object is something you create in client-side JavaScript and give it to fullCalendar to tell it how to handle the event source. Your JSON response from the server must contain just the array of events.

Comment: P.S. You say "Now I want to use the option of eventSources,"...but `calendar.addEventSource(eventSource);` indicates that you're already using that feature. The only difference is you're supplying a simple URL string to the function rather than a full object. This is allowed and valid. Unless you're planning to set some of the other properties of the event source object as well, then you don't actually have a need to change anything at all.

Comment: @ jagad89 - not working, already tried. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks. You are right, I am already using EventSource. But now I want to set some of the other properties of the event source as well like id & color. I want to use id property, so that I can delete all the events of one perticular id with one statement.Please tell me how would I set them.

Comment: You set them on the client side, not the server side. Create an object in your JavaScript and assign properties to it as needed. Does that make sense? If not, I can write an example

Comment: @ADyson - Please write an example for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood, that's not how the event sources feature works. The idea of event sources is to define multiple different sources from which to download event data. Each source can have its own properties as well, defined by creating an [event source object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object) - but this is something you do in the JavaScript code, not in the server-side JSON.

The server-side JSON is just used to create the array of actual events, not the data about the event source. The event source defines (among other things) the place to get the events from (i.e. the URL on the server), so it's not logical to wait until that URL is visited before defining the event source - it's too late by then.

Here's how you define an event source object correctly:

```
var eventSource = {
  "id": 1, 
  "url": "data.php?value1=" + item_id,
  "color" : "black"
}
calendar.addEventSource(eventSource);
```